# Nginx bottleneck as load balancer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, postgresql, nginx

We have a popular iPhone app where people duel each other a la Wordfeud. We have almost 1 M registered users today.

During peak hours the app gets really long response times, and there are also quite a lot of time outs. We have tried to find the bottleneck, but have had a hard time doing so. 
CPU, memory and I/O are all under 50 % on all servers. The problem ONLY appears during peak hours.

**Our setup**

```
1 VPS with nginx (1.1.9) as load balancer
4 front servers with Ruby (1.9.3p194) on Rails (3.2.5) / Unicorn (4.3.1)
1 database server with PostgreSQL 9.1.5
```

The database logs doesn't show enough long request times to explain all the timeouts shown in the nginx error log.

We have also tried to build and run the app directly against the front servers (during peak hour when all other users are running against the load balancer). The surprising thing is that the app bypassing the load balancer is quick as a bullet even under peak hours.

**NGINX SETTINGS**

```
worker_processes=16
worker_connections=4096
multi_accept=on
```

**LINUX SETTINGS**

```
fs.file-max=13184484
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem="4096 87380 4194304"
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem="4096 16384 4194304"
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="32768 61000"
```

Why is the app bypassing the load balancer so fast?
Can nginx as load balancer be the bottle neck?
Is there any good way to compare timeouts in nginx with timeouts in the unicorns to see where the problem resides?

Comment: Do I understand, that the balancer works under virtualization while the fronts and database servers are hardware?

Comment: All servers are virtualized, none are hardware.

Comment: Performance and virtualization are incompatible concepts. What's in nginx error logs?

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your settings nginx might be the bottleneck...

Check/tune the following settings in nginx:

1. the `worker_processes` setting (should be equal to the number of cores/cpus)
2. the `worker_connections` setting (should be very high if you have lots of connections at peak)
3. set `multi_accept on;`
4. if on linux, in nginx make sure you're using epoll (`use epoll;`-directive)

check/tune the following settings of your OS:

1. number of allowed open file descriptors (`sysctl -w fs.file-max=999999` on linux)
2. tcp read and write buffers (`sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_rmem="4096 4096 16777216"` and 
   `sysctl - net.ipv4.tcp_wmem="4096 4096 16777216"` on linux)
3. local port range (`sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="1024 65536"` on linux)

Update:

- so you have 16 workers and 4096 connections per workers
- which means a maximum of 4096*16=65536 concurrent connections
- you probably have multiple requests per browser (ajax, css, js, page itself, any images on the page, ...), let's say 4 request per browser

that allows for slightly over 16k concurrent users, is that enough for your peaks?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Cobaco! I added our settings to the questions above. See anything strange there? We don't have the "use epoll" in the conf file. But I wasn't able to tell what event handling we currently use. I read that it is put out as a log notice when starting nginx, but couldn't find it in error.log or access.log. Do you know how to see which event handler nginx currently uses?

Comment: Just replace `multi_accept on;` with `multi_accept on; use epoll;`, That way you can be sure you are using epoll. http://nginx.org/en/docs/events.html doesn't mention anything about log output, and I can't find anything in mine regarding the used option either.

Answer (score 0):

How do you set up your upstream server group and what is the load balancing method you use?

It's hard to imagine that Nginx itself is the bottleneck. Is it possible that some upstream app servers get hit much more than others and start to refuse connection due to backlog is full? See this [load balancing issue on Heroku](http://rapgenius.com/James-somers-herokus-ugly-secret-lyrics) and see if you can get more help there.

After nginx version 1.2.2, nginx provides this [`least_conn`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#least_conn). That might be an easy fix. I haven't tried it myself yet.

> Specifies that a group should use a load balancing method where a
>   request is passed to the server with the least number of active
>   connections, taking into account weights of servers. If there are
>   several such servers, they are tried using a weighted round-robin
>   balancing method.